# How to query MySQL to include given a pair of unix timestamps inclusive of overlaps?

Tags: mysql

I am querying a MySQL database using a php script based on the `start` and `end` unix timestamps (integer) passed to it from FullCalendar.js's ajax load event. A simplified version of the query is as follows :

```
SELECT
   * FROM `events`
WHERE
  `start` >= :start AND
  `end` <= :end
```

This query has the following two types of events being excluded which I wish to include in the resultset returned from the query:

- Events which the start date stored in the database is prior to the start date being queried.
- Events which the end date stored in the database is after the end date being queried.
- Events which meet both of the above criteria.

Both event types which are being excluded that I wish to include, have events which partially fall in the range being queried for.

The following dates used are in a more readable format to make the problem more visible. Actual data is in unix timestamp (integer) format.

Example data received by the php script which is passed to the respective locations in the SQL query:

```
{
    "start": "10/28/2018",
    "end": "12/03/2018"
}
```

## Example of events stored in database

Start is prior, but event duration has days in range

```
start: 10/19/2018
end: 11/04/2018
```

End is after, but event duration has days in range

```
start: 11/22/2018
end: 12/13/2018
```

Start is before, and End is after, but event duration has days in range

```
start: 10/19/2018
end: 12/13/2018
```

How can my query be rewritten so that given a start and end date, any record which has days that fall within the range specified ?

Comment: Generally, Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends and ends after Event B starts.

Comment: @Strawberry - That resolved it.  Thank you.  `  `start` <= :end AND
   `end` >= :start `